# Querying another database from a Firebase Realtime Trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a firebase realtime trigger that will query another database in the same project onWrite. How can i do so ?

```
  exports.trackit = functions.database.ref('/tags/{readId}').onWrite(event => {
  const snaps = event.data;
  var ref = functions.database().ref('/routes');

  ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val());
  }, function (error) {
     console.log("Error: " + error.code);
  });
})
```

The above is a sample code put together from the samples and reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have been looking at the wrong samples and docs then. This example from [the documentation on creating your first function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions#add_the_addmessage_function) has an example:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
// Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push it into the Realtime Database then send a response
  admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
});
```

So use `var ref = admin.database().ref('/routes')`.

Also see the [full code in the github repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js#L27-L39).

Comment: Thank You Sir, that helped a lot!